# Why is jQuery hasClass returning a TypeError?

Tags: jquery

On the [`hasClass` documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) there is the following div element:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="widget-area" role="complementary">…</div>
```

However, when I enter the following into the console on this page:

```
$('.widget-area').hasClass('widget-area'); // This should return true!
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hasClass is not a function(…)

I understand that this is because jQuery is returning a DOM element here, but I don't understand why. I'm using the exact same syntax as on that very page of documentation and getting a different response.

Comment: `$(...)` never returns a DOM element in jQuery. You're not using the jQuery `$` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely executing `$('.widget-area').hasClass('widget-area');` in another frame. In Chrome, there's a dropdown on the top-left of the console that specifies in which frame the console is executing commands. Change it to `top` and it should work.